# Create a maximo Endpoint for an external SOAP Webservice

Tags: integration, maximo

I'm trying to find out if I miss something. I'm trying to create an endpoint in Maximo foar a Soap WebService. I've tested it with soap ui and everything works perfect. In maximo I set the Url, username, password and SOAPACTION (GET). But it doesn;t work..I get the message to check the log but I cannot find anything relevant in there. Does anyone know if I need to make some additional settings before? Or maybe I miss something ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same issue now